# Handle duplicates and fInd the records with last modified date in the same table - Hive

Tags: sql, filter, hive, duplicates, max

I have a table with email address, a flag and last modified date. This table contains the history of all changes captured in the last modified date as opposed to just the incremental changes of flag. For eg: If an email aa@gmail.com has a flag of Y on 1/19/2021 and value of N on 1/20/2021, both of those will be available in this table. I am querying in Hive.

What I want is to just find the counts of email with the max last modified date.

eg:

```
Email           flag  last modified date
aa@gmail.com      Y.   1/19/2021
aa@gmail.com.     N.   1/20/2021
```

I want

```
Email           flag  last modified date
aa@gmail.com      N.   1/20/2021
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by email order by modified_date desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you clarify what t.* stands for? The row_number for some reason made all seqnum = 1, so I used rank and it worked.

Comment: @DSSD . . . `t.*` select all columns from the table reference through the alias `t`.